# Port ~1m partial objects from Firebase to my own database (mongo)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bigdata

I am looking for a way to transfer about 1 million records from my Firebase's `users` table to a new MongoDB's `users` collection I've created on my own server. I want to bring in only some data such as the `age`, `username`, and `name`. I would use Mongo for "fast retrieval" for display in profile pages (because profile pages require me to get the user data before even loading any of the page's data, I am looking to optimize this part as much as possible).

Enough about context. Real question -- how may I get 1m records from Firebase? I tried fetching records by doing `limitToFirst(500000)` and then `limitToLast(500000)` (to then loop through the records and store in mongo) but that's still way too big.

Comment: just write a script to pull it in smaller chunks and leave it running over night

Comment: How to do that? There is no "skip" function.

Comment: There are `.startAt` and .`endAt` but I don't know how it applies as there's no index in Firebase. Any way to use startAt/endAt on the Firebase's UID key (given Firebase internally processes the uid and there's a timestamp in there or something)?

Comment: There is no way to retrieve partial nodes from the Firebase Database. I'd recommend either using a [private backup](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/announcing-automated-daily-backups-for-the-firebase-database.html) or a tool like [firebak](https://github.com/alexklibisz/firebak), which creates incremental backups through the API. If you've already tried using the API to export the data, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have the 500GB file on my server. Simply put, Nodejs crashes when I import that file to try to use it as an object... Will check about your incremental backup suggestion.